# Log4j exception lead to application abort

Tags: log4j, flume

My java application use log4j(flume appender with AsyncAppender) to log to remote log server. 
If log server is down, log4j will try to reconnect a few times,but then my java application was shutdown.Is there any possible my java application goes normal with the exception of log4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right solution is :
use AsyncAppender with FlumeAppender. more detail see http://edwardsbean.github.io/blog/2014/01/14/flume-in-action-1/

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

1. Catch the exception and ignore it
2. set the **[UnsafeMode](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#log4j-appender)** property to true.